# Setting the limiting condition of for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

having a problem with my for loop, I'm sure it is something simple I am missing, but, I am try to get three loaded images to move 10 increments down, and then stop (with the three images stopped at 10 increments down.
when I run the code, it runs down, but it runs off the page (doesn't stop at 10). Can anyone see the issue?
any help would be great!

```
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded()
{
    canvasApp();
}


function canvasSupport () 
{
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}

function canvasApp()
{
    if (!canvasSupport()) 
    {
        return;
}

    else
{
    theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
}

var toes = new Image();
toes.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
toes.src = "images/toes.png";
var larry = new Image();
larry.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
larry.src = "images/larry.png";
var barry = new Image();
barry.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
barry.src = "images/barry.png";

function eventShipLoaded()
{
    startUp();
}

y=0;

function drawScreen()
{

    for (x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
            context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
            context.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
            context.drawImage(toes,0,y,114,339);
            context.drawImage(larry,110,(y+81),86,258);
            context.drawImage(barry,203,(y+72),98,265);
            y+=1;
    }
}


function startUp() 
{
    setInterval(drawScreen,5);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see a single while loop in that code? What is `for (x=0; x<1;x++)` used for? That loop does not make any sense at all.

Comment: sorry, I screwed up, was a for loop, not while. if I only incremented by 1 until my for loop reached 10, I would still need to limit my y?, sorry, screwed up, was trying both fors and whiles, either way, was a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the value for y. you only have

```
  y+=1;
```

Comment: sorry, I screwed up, was a for loop, not while. if I only incremented by 1 until my for loop reached 10, I would still need to limit my y?

Answer (score 0):

You're using "setInterval" without ever unsetting the timer. That's why the images keep moving. So just count how many times "drawScreen" gets called and stop the timer after the 10th call:

```
var movements = 0;
var timer = null;

function drawScreen() {
    // ... original code ...

    if (timer && ++movements == 10) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

function startup() {
    timer = setInterval(drawScreen, 5);
}
```

Comment: still runnin off--  y = 0;
 var movements = 0;
 var timer = null;
 
 
 function drawScreen()
 {
  
  for (x = 0; x < 1; x++)
  {
    context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
    context.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
    context.drawImage(jellytoes,0,y,114,339);
    context.drawImage(larry,110,(y+81),86,258);
    context.drawImage(barry,203,(y+72),98,265);
    y+=1;
  
  }
  
  if (timer && ++movements == 10) 
  {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }
  
  
 }
 
 
 function startUp() 
 {
  timer = setInterval(drawScreen, 5);
 }

Comment: sorry, I'm not great with figuring out how to work around posting my comments/ commenting on other posts